# Performance Counters to be used for Python web applications

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I wanted to know which are the counters should be used in windows Performance Monitor for the applications developed in python.

Thanks,
Theju

Answer (score 0):

The tool you need is called a profiler. There are various profilers for python my favorites are `cProfile` and `vprof` here are some links to begin:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

https://github.com/nvdv/vprof